# Cognos report outputting different result sets

Tags: parameters, reporting, cognos-8

My work uses Cognos 8.3 for our reports.  I have been given a task in resolving an issue where a particular report displays different data for the same request.

I have a report that takes in a multi-valued parameter (`p_id=123&p_id=456`).  It is supposed to display information for those two records (123 & 456), but the first time I launch the report, it only shows the info for one of them.  If I close out and relaunch it (without changing the url), it shows the info for both records.  I have verified that the URL is correct and the same between the two launches.  I have found via SQL Profiler that the first time i run the report, the query is getting the values wrong ( "`WHERE id IN ('123', '123')`"), while the second (and subsequent) time I run it it is run correctly ("`WHERE id IN ('123', '456')`").  I am able to consistently reproduce this.

Now I do not know that much about Cognos, but is there perhaps some sort of setting in the report or elsewhere that could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Ths Dan... I remember this being an issue that i believe was fixed in a fix-pack... but can you also do something to see if we can work around it...  There are many ways to work around it but trying to avoid coding first.

1. Create a  multi select prompt with the same name p_id on the report canvase with 1 default value or 2 default values and retry. The default values should be values that you know will never be used (Perhaps negative numbers).

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: Caching is turned off and the multi-values are coming from parameters in the URL which is generated by an external web tool

Comment: Ths Dan... I remember this being an issue that i believe was fixed in a fix-pack... but can you also do something to see if we can work around it... There are many ways to work around it but trying to avoid coding first.
 1.Create a multi select prompt with the same name p_id on the report canvase with 1 default value or 2 default values and retry. The default values should be values that you know will never be used (Perhaps negative numbers). 

Thanks,

Tim